# I can't reach my VBox SQL machine from my Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I get a SQL server environment in a virtual machine Windows 8. I'm using **VirtualBox version 5.2.4** to run my virtual environments. My goal is to reach out the SQL from Excel or any other app like Tableau or PowerBI. So far as I know I have to ensure everything about the security part in my SQL service and also ensure the communication within both machines.

Communication issue.

I'm using NAT configuration and as you can see in the image below the virtual machine can get a valid IP and even go thru internet. Otherwise, in my localhost computer, I don't have any IP related to the virtual one to run a ping and get the communication.

[image]

I edit my NAT connection like:

[image]

And then I tried to get the connection in Excel like:

[image]

I went a little bit through the documentation and even I read that is recommended configure in my VirtualBox adapter like **Host-only Adapter**. However, When I try to use this option, I don't have any available adapter from the list.

[image]

Please if someone can give me a clue I appreciate.

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first create the Host-Only adapter to be available in your virtual machine. Go to File > Preferences > Network > Host-Only Networks (It should be empty, the item from the screenshot is one I already have). Then click the add button.

[image]

[image]

After that you have to configure your newly created adapter:

[image]

Save and go to the settings of your virtual machine. Now you should be able to select the Host-Only adapter.

[image]

Save this settings and boot into your guest OS. Now you should be able to ping to the guest OS.

Comment: Trying monsieur I will keep you posted give me a couple of hours, sounds very strong and nice approach

Comment: My friend, I`m back, I have added a new network card I suppose following your steps, but either way when I try to join this net card with my VM configuration it doesnt go thru. I get a feeling on the VBox version. Mine is 5.2.4 what is yours? thanks

Comment: Hmm... Maybe its something related with the Windows guest. Using Win 10 as host and Linux as guest it works. The other way around I can only ping from guest to host. Another way would be to configure the network as Bridged instead of NAT, but that means your VM will be exposed to the entire network. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Finally I reinstalled the VBox Version and the additional options were installed. Therefore my issue was solved.  thanks so much